# How can I make Fedora 20 use the dark theme for all applications?

Tags: fedora, themes, gtk, color-theme

If it's somehow possible to force all programs to use the dark adwaita theme, I wish to do that. For now it only seems as if the apps that shipped with Fedora is able to be fully dark, while everything else I use looks like the standard white theme.

I managed to make the top bar be dark by changing /usr/share/themes/adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css to be just a copy of gtk-dark.css from that same folder, but that's not quite enough as it only fixes the top bar and not everything.

For example, this is what firefox looks like:
[image]

So how can I make all the apps look nice and dark like nautilus and the standard Fedora apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already discovered half of the solution: It’s a GTK theme. It applies only to applications using a GTK GUI. This is the same for both shipped and third-party applications.

Firefox does not use GTK and, as such, does not use the theme. There is absolutely nothing you can do to change this, except perhaps reinvent Firefox. ;) Still, there may be themes available (for Firefox at least) that match your preferences.

Comment: "Firefox does not use GTK" - that is completely wrong. Firefox uses gtk2 (on linux) but since gnome 3 uses gtk3, changing the theme only affects gtk3 apps, not gtk2 ones. So yes, there is something you can do, namely change the [gtk2 theme](http://askubuntu.com/a/337021).

Comment: Many GUI widgets in Firefox are not GTK widgets but custom-made by Mozilla. This is also true on Windows. So unless the OP is satisfied with buttons, title bars and the like, this won’t suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
env GTK_THEME=Breeze:dark firefox
```

of set you theme for gtk2 under

```
~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, for other people who may wonder, a way to have all gnome3 applications using a dark theme is to put the following in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and ***restart session*** (the `r` command at the alt+F2 prompt trick doesn't seems to work) :

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme = true
```

Now I don't know if such a property exists to configure gtk2 applications.